# Leverage browser catching for google plus button and analytics (2)

Tags: browser, web, try-catch, browser-cache, pagespeed

This is the code I put in my htaccess file but it is not working. Maybe I am missing something? or doing something wrong? Help if you can, please.

```
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/png "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/css "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access plus 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access plus 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access plus 1 week"
```

But, After adding google plus one button to my site and adding google analytics I get these two sugestions on gtmetrix.com

The following cacheable resources have a short freshness lifetime. Specify an expiration at least one week in the future for the following resources:

https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js (30 minutes)
http://www.google-analytics.com/ga.js (12 hours)

How do i write the code in the htaccess to leverage browser catching for these 2. And is it a good idea to leverage browser catching from for google analytics?

Answer (score 3):

It is not possible to control the expiration time of those two resources by modifying **your** server's settings. The expiration header has to be set by the origin server (therefore only Google can do that)